# ¿Como hago referencia a un metodo del controller con un <a>?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc

tengo una etiqueta

```
<a href="/Aplicacion/cerrar-sesion" >Cerrar Sesión</a>
```

referenciando un metodo en el controlador

```
[RoutePrefix("Aplicacion")]
    public class AplicacionController : Controller
    {
[Route("cerrar-sesion"), HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ValidarUsuario()
        {
            //Codigo
        }
    }
```

pero no recuerdo como hacerle referencia, ya le di el atributo href pero al ejecutar el proyecto y darle click me sale el error 404, creo que le falta algun atributo ya que en el controlador esta bien y ademas al usar un `<form>` aparte del `action=""` le doy el atributo `method="post"`, pero en la etiqueta `<a>` no tiene ese atributo.
alguien me puede decir que atributo es o si el problema es otro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un link de html solo funciona como `GET` el `POST` no aplica a menos que realices el `submit` del form

Puedes eliminar el `HttpPost` dejando

```
[Route("cerrar-sesion")]
public ActionResult ValidarUsuario()
{
    //Codigo
}
```

Para que funcione con el link

Ahora, si realizas un post deberia ser reemplazado

```
<form action='@Url.Action("cerrar-sesion","Aplicacion")' method="post">
  <button type="submit">Cerrar</button>
</form>
```

Entonces si deberia invocarlo ya que realizas un post a ese action